# Multiple files in a JavaScript program

Tags: javascript, file, module

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to mess around with the language to grasp it better. One thing that I cannot seem to understand, is how developers structure big JavaScript programs. I assumed that you would break it down into a bunch of smaller files like you would in Java. Apparently you don't do this in JavaScript.. Is everything in one massive file? That seems incorrect to me.

For example, I wanted to have two files, one with all my helper functions and one with the problem-specific functions. I was planning on using the helper functions in my problem-specific file.

If I am supposed to put things in one big file, do I split it up with modules? Sorry for such a lengthy post, I'm very confused and I'm not exactly sure how I should word it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need any fancy js plugin to do this, just include your "header files" (all your function declarations) before your main js file in the html.

Example:

file1.js:

```
//declare your functions here
function handyFunction() {
 //do some handy stuff
}
```

file2.js:

```
//use them here
handyFunction();
```

html:

```
<body>
<!-- all your html here -->
<script src="file1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

If you don't feel comfortable having everything on the global object, you can have objects that contain the methods you need and create instances of them as necessary or access the instances previously created. Just a simple example:

MyObject.js:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.property = "someValue";
}

MyObject.prototype.someMethod = function () {
    //do something
}
```

main.js:

```
var obj= new MyObject();
obj.someMethod();
```

html:

```
<!-- always remember to include your files in the correct order -->
<script src="MyObject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Ok, one last clarification. In JavaScript, every variable is declared inside the scope of a function, unless there is none in which case it is appended to the window object. This is called function scope and is a BIG difference with other languages. What this means is that everything you declare in a file will 1) get appended to the global object (window) or 2) be accessible only to the function inside which it was declared.
So, if you want to "anonymize" some code, you can wrap an autoexecuting anonymous function around it and since the function has no variable referrencing to it, that code won't be accessible by anyone outside of it. This is why you see `(function() { /*...*/}());` in a lot of places.
So, how do I share code that was declared in this way between files? Simple, give it a name! And thus the module pattern is created. In the first file, you declare all your code inside a variable named "module" or whatever floats your goat, and inside it you put all your methods in the fanciest way you like (for example, by using an anonymous function and returning an object). The trick is to have this "module" object declared on the global object to be able to use it across files in your application. There really isn't much more to it.

Comment: Don't put JS in the `head`.

Comment: What if I used a module pattern? Can I still call the function directly like that (as long as it's 'public' of course)?

Comment: what do you mean by module? There's not such thing in javascript. If you create an object containing multiple methods, the object will be accessible in the next script by whatever name you called it

Comment: I'm not sure what the proper term is but this is what I mean: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247241/Javascript-Module-Pattern

Everything is wrapped in a self-executing function to create 'private' variables/functions.

Comment: see my edit and tell me if that clarifies your question. Module pattern would work on a similar way, if you declared all functions inside the "Module" global variable in the example

Comment: Yes, you can do the same with a Javascript module pattern. You can split modules over multiple files and add then to a global namespace object to help divide your code up into manageable chunks while still forming a unified application.

Comment: You're final edit helped a lot! I didn't down vote you. I would up vote you if I could! Last question (hopefully), once I name my module can I access the function/variables of it like so: moduleName.functionName();

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you do it :)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how large your application is. If it's a one off form handler, you could probably put all your logic in one file. However, if it's a larger, single page application, you'll want to look at breaking it up into multiple files. How the files interact with eachother depends on the order in which they are included in the page. For example, if one file depends on another, make sure the script is included in your page after the primary script.

To help better organize your dependencies (rather than managing the script inclusion order yourself), and to set you off on the right foot, you should probably take a look at RequireJS:
http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Here's a third party intro and tutorial
http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/07/requirejs-amd-tutorial-introduction/

As for your Module Pattern question, you could use a module pattern, but you would still run into the same dependency issue if one module in one file depended on another in a separate file. You might want to check out this chapter from Eloquent Javascript: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter9.html

Comment: RequireJS is awesome! I'll probably use that later on, I still need to figure out jQuery/Underscore...